# Trying to get property of non-object error when using json,php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, json

I am using AngularJS to get the input from a form, sending the data to a php using console.log function and decoding the json file using php, then checking a database to find info matching the input values.here my code

login.html

```
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
<form action="/" id="mylogin">
    Username: <input type="text" id="username" ng-model="username" ><br>
    Password: <input type="password" id="password1" ng-model="password1">
    <button type="button" ng-click="submit()">Login</button>
</form>
```

controller.js

```
 app.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
 $scope.submit = function () {
    alert($scope.username);
        $http.post('php/userlogin.php',{'username' : $scope.username}).success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if (data == true) {
                alert('aaa');
                                }
            });
            } 
});
```

php/userlogin.php

```
<?php 
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  $user=$data->username;
  include("include/db.php");
  $select_user = mysql_query("select * from userlogin where username='".$user."'" );
  $result = mysql_fetch_array($select_user);
  $user_id=$view_prof['user_id'];
    if($user_id != "" )
        {
            echo "1";
        }
    else
        {
            echo "0";
        }
?>
```

Comment: aren't you suppose to use $_POST/$_REQUEST in getting the data from a request?. and also, you use file_get_contents the wrong way

Comment: can you show me a sample @Semi-Friends

Comment: [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm)

Comment: @RaviKumar : can you please try my code?

Answer (score 0):

**Basically problem is in header content type.** 
Either Code it like this or let me know if you still not get post variable in php :

### controller

```
 app.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
 $scope.submit = function () {
    alert($scope.username);
        $http.post('php/userlogin.php',{'username' : $scope.username},{transformRequest: angular.identity, headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}).success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if (data == true) {
                alert('aaa');
                                }
            });
            } 
});
```

### php file

```
<?php 
var_dump($_POST); // you will surely get this.
?>
```

Comment: where i want to use this in php file @Jigar7521

Comment: You can have all data like this in your php file :  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); **replace it  by**  $data = $_POST;

Comment: let me know if you want me to make working code snippet

Comment: <?php
     $data = $_POST;
     $user=$data->username;
     include("include/db.php");
     //var_dump($_POST['username']);
     $select_user = mysql_query("select * from userlogin where    username='".$user."'" );
     $result = mysql_fetch_array($select_user);
 $user_id=$view_prof['user_id'];
  if($user_id != "" )
   {
    echo "1";
   }
  else
   {
    echo "0";
   }
         ?>
this is correct @Jigar7521

Comment: i don't got what you are saying

Comment: i am the php code but its not working. so change my code and post here @jigar7521

Comment: i did't know how to get the $_POST value in the userlogin.php.@Jigar7521